# Programa no imprime nada en cmd

Tags: c, cmd, contraseña, parámetros

Soy un estudiante e hice este programa de un generador de contraseñas en C utilizando parámetros que van a consola y son proporcionados por el usuario, donde el primer parámetro es siempre la longitud de la contraseña y el resto de ellos son qué caracteres quieres que tenga la contraseña, ya sean mayúsculas ("-M"), etc... Y si no se pone ningún parámetro o no es alguno definido, pone mensajes de error.

El programa lleva a compilar bien, pero cuando tengo que compilarlo desde consola y pongo cualquier parámetro relacionado con la longitud de la contraseña, simplemente no sale nada en la consola de comandos (cmd) y es como si se quedase cargando, no sale ni mensaje de error ni nada. Supongo que será de algún error del código o algo así, asique os lo dejo por aquí.

Realmente agradecería si me pudieses corregir los errores y ya por fin hacer que el programa funcione, porque llevo una semana con esto y tremendo dolor de cabeza tengo. (La programación desde luego no está hecha para mi). Gracias.

**passwordgenerator.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/* Cada uno de los parámetros necesarios para utilizar en la consola*/

int mayusculas = 0;
int minusculas = 0;
int digitos = 0;
int especiales = 0;
unsigned int longitud_clave;

#define CARACTERES_ESPECIALES "!@#$^&*?"

/* Comprobamos que existe más de un parámetro (el nombre) en la línea de comandos */

if(argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Primero, debes introducir la longitud de la clave.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*El 1º parámetro siempre va a ser la longitud de la contraseña*/

if(sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &longitud_clave) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "El primer parametro debe ser un entero. Vuelve a ingresar la longitud.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*A partir del 2º parámetro pueden ser mayúsculas, minúsculas...*/

for (int i=2; i<argc; i++){
 
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-M") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-n") == 0){

        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-ce") == 0){

        especiales = 1;
    }
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-d") == 0){

        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-Mn") == 0 || strcmp(argv[i], "-nM") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(argv[i], "-ndM") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "-nMd")) == 0 || ((strcmp(argv[i], "-dnM") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "-Mnd")) == 0)){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-all") == 0){

        mayusculas = 1;
        minusculas = 1;
        digitos = 1;
        especiales = 1;
    }
    else{

        fprintf(stderr, "Clave no v%clida. Debes utilizar los par%cmetros indicados:", 160, 160);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n-M, -n, -ce, -d, -Mn/-nM, -Mnd (y sus combinaciones) y -all");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
/*Creamos el alfabeto de todos los parámetros para luego hacer la contraseña libremente*/

int tam_alfabeto = 1; // Para finalizar la cadena - depuración
if (mayusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
if (minusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'z' - 'a' + 1;
if (digitos)    tam_alfabeto += 10;
if (especiales) tam_alfabeto += strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES);

char * alfabeto = (char*)malloc(tam_alfabeto * sizeof(char));
int index = 0;

for (char c='A'; c<='Z' && mayusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='a'; c<='z' && minusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='0'; c<='9' && digitos; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (int i=0; i<strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES) && especiales; i++)
    alfabeto[index++] = CARACTERES_ESPECIALES[i]; 

alfabeto[index] = 0; // Solo para fines de depuración

/*Generamos la contraseña*/

srand(time(NULL));

int clave_ok;
char*clave = (char*)malloc((longitud_clave+1)*sizeof(char));
for( int i=0; i<longitud_clave; i++){

    clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
    clave[i] = 0; // Finalizamos la cadena
}
/*Hacemos una comprobación para que la contraseña tenga los parámetros que queremos*/

    do{
    
        for( int i=0; i<longitud_clave; i++){
        
            clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
        }
 
        int hay_mayusculas = 0;
        int hay_minusculas = 0;
        int hay_digitos    = 0;
        int hay_especiales = 0;
 
        for (int i=0; i<longitud_clave; i++){
        
            hay_mayusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'A' && clave[i] <= 'Z');
            hay_minusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'a' && clave[i] <= 'z');
            hay_digitos    |= (clave[i] >= '0' && clave[i] <= '9');
            hay_especiales |= (strchr(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES, clave[i]) != NULL);
        }
 
        clave_ok = 1;
        if (mayusculas) clave_ok &= hay_mayusculas;
        if (minusculas) clave_ok &= hay_minusculas;
        if (digitos)    clave_ok &= hay_digitos;
        if (especiales) clave_ok &= hay_especiales;
 
        if (!clave_ok){
        
            printf("Clave no valida: %s\n", clave);
            exit(-1);
        }
    } while (!clave_ok);
 
    printf("Clave generada: %s\n", clave);
    free(clave);
}
```

**Respuesta a @FreddyJS**

Si te refieres a tenerlo así:

```
/*Generamos la contraseña*/

srand(time(NULL));
    
int clave_ok;
char*clave = (char*)malloc((longitud_clave+1)*sizeof(char));
clave[longitud_clave] = 0;
     for( int i=0; i<longitud_clave; i++){
    
     clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
}
```

O así:

```
/*Generamos la contraseña*/

srand(time(NULL));

int clave_ok;
char*clave = (char*)malloc((longitud_clave+1)*sizeof(char));
for( int i=0; i<longitud_clave; i++){

    clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
}

    clave[longitud_clave] = 0;
```

Ninguno de los dos me ha funcionado.
Aunque tengo que decir una cosa, y es que cuando pongo como parámetro "-10 o -20" se me queda pillado cmd y no hace nada, pero si como "10 o 20" me muestra una contraseña, pero realmente no tiene la longitud que debería. Es realmente extraño.

Comment: En el for donde generas la clave estas igualando el mismo char a una letra aleatoria y justo después a 0. Asique queda una String vacía, debería ser `clave[longitud_clave] = 0` y lo puedes hacer directamente antes del for o despues

Comment: Te he respondido editando la pregunta, para que veas si realmente te refieres a eso y veas específicamente el problema que me surge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema viene por la forma en que pasas por parámetros la longitud de la clave.
Si la pasas como "-10" al guardarlo como unsigned int obtienes un 4294967286:

```cpp
sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &longitud_clave);
```

Si saltas ese caracter '-' puedes seguir pasando los argumentos del mismo modo:

```cpp
sscanf(argv[1] +1, "%u", &longitud_clave);
```

E igualmente para finalizar la cadena basta con un:

```cpp
clave[longitud_clave] = 0;
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya me funciona como debería, muchísimas gracias.